# using document.images.src property in javascript i want to get list of images source

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am able to get it when hardcoding but throwing error while trying it with for loop.

```
for(i=0;i<document.images.length;i++)
       {
            document.writeln(document.images[i].src);  
       }
```

actually after printing first index value loop is terminating
error:cannot read object property src....

but below hardcoded one is working fine:

```
document.write(document.images[0].src); 
document.write(document.images[1].src); 
document.write(document.images[2].src); 
document.write(document.images[3].src);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are performing `document.write` or `writeln` it performs `window.open` (if the page was loaded w/o calling it) and erases all the content of the page, so after the first call of `writeln` in loop `document.images` will be an empty array.

In this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qar6J/) you can see an alert after the loop that shows count of images in the document. Regarding this, i can't understand how could your second example (without loop) work. It might broke down after executing the first line.

**EDIT:**

To make this work you might accumulate your `src`s and print them at once like:

```
var text = "";
var linebreak = "<br />";    
for(i=0;i<document.images.length;i++)
       {
           text += document.images[i].src;
           text += linebreak;
       }

document.write(text);
```

Comment: thats what am wondering.i am able to display all the images through second example but not with for loop.How to overcome this?? any idea??Is there any other way to solve this

Comment: Then how to get the src of all the images.Direct me through some sample code .Thnx 4 ur reply

Comment: just don't use `document.write` method, append data to div or make a list - anything except `write`/`writeln`

Comment: Thats good idea but im new to programming and i have no idea to do all this stuff.can u please help me through some sample code.

Comment: ok thanks.But can u do me a favour by pasting the code.URL to that link is blocked in my institute.